# Abstract method in public abstract class implementing an internal interface doesn't compile?

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
internal interface I_Foo
{
    void Bar();
}

public abstract class A_Foo : I_Foo
{
    public A_Foo() { }
    abstract void I_Foo.Bar();
}

public class Foo : A_Foo
{
    public Foo() : base() { }
    internal override void Bar()
    {

    }
}
```

Hello! I'm trying to have some methods visible to outside code, and other only visible to my assembly. For this purpose, I made an internal interface I_Foo to serve as a contract to other parts of the assembly, a public abstract A_Foo to serve as abstraction for external code, and centralize some constructor functionality, and several different classes Foo that implement A_Foo and I_Foo explicitly to retain internal modifier.

However, in the A_Foo class, I get

> 'A_Foo.I_Foo.Bar()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

even though the method is clearly marked as "abstract". If I add a body, I get "abstract is not a valid modifier".

I need this method to be explicitly declared, in order to be internal in a public class, and I need it to be abstract so I can override it in the actual implementation Foo.

Why doesn't the compiler let me?
Is there another way I can achieve the same thing?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do the methods have to be A_Foo?

Comment: `public A_Foo()` should probably be `protected A_Foo()` which is the default anyway for abstract classes. By the nature of abstract classes, their constructors can only be used inside inheriting classes, so usually the `public` modifier (and also the `protected internal` combination) is avoided for their constructors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Explicit interface implementations always have to have an actual implementation. The trick here is to making that just call a *non-explicit* (internal) abstract method:

```
public abstract class A_Foo : I_Foo
{
    // Classes outside the assembly can't derive from A_Foo
    // anyway, so let's make the constructor internal...
    internal A_Foo() { }

    void I_Foo.Bar()
    {
        Bar(); // Just delegate to the abstract method
    }

    internal abstract void Bar();
}
```

This still allows `I_Foo` to use internal types etc, because `Bar` is never exposed publicly - but it fits within the other rules of the language.

Comment: Perfect, clean, and works. I'll accept it as an answer in 6 minutes :) Thank you!

Comment: I know the question also had `internal` for `Bar`, but maybe it was better to have it `protected`? If it really needs to be `internal`, the instance constructor should be `internal` as well, because a (public) class with an `internal abstract` method cannot be inherited from another project.

Comment: @JeppeStig: Sometimes that's exactly what you want though. We use that pattern in Noda Time for CalendarSystem in 1.x. It was a public abstract type, but other assemblies couldn't derive from it, deliberately.

Comment: I agree, that is fine. I would make sure all instance constructors were `internal` (or `private`) in that case (and in your answer). For example, `System.Globalization.EastAsianLunisolarCalendar` is a (non-nested) public abstract type with several `internal abstract` properties and methods. If you try to derive from it outside `mscorlib.dll`, you get a bunch of compile-time errors, many of the revealing those internal members. However, one of the errors explains there is no constructor available. That is because they took care and made the constructor `internal`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Have made the constructor internal.

Answer (score 3):

The method can not be abstract. THe problem is that you try to use explicit interface implementation (void I_Foo.Bar). Those methods can not be overwritten later - so they have to be implemented.

If you declare Bar directly (`void Bar()`) then it can be abstract.

Comment: No, because it would have to be public to implement the interface, and the OP doesn't *want* it to be public. In other words, this doesn't solve the motivation behind the question. (Imagine that `Bar` actually used an internal type as a parameter, for example.)